Developing an API with Oak from Deno: TypeError - request.body is not a function
I'm learning how to develop an API with Deno's Oak by doing basic queries on a list of products.
Except I have an error that I can't fix

TypeError - request.body is not a function

const addProduct = async(
    { request, response } : { request: any, response: any },
) => {
    const body = await request.body(); // <-- here

    if (!request.hasBody) {
        response.status = 400;
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: "No data",
        };
    }
    else {
        const product: Product = body.value;
        products.push(product);
        response.status = 201;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: product,
        };
    }
};

Having other requests in my code I am sharing only part of it with you
export { getProducts, getProduct, addProduct, updateProduct, deleteProduct };
To call it in route.ts:
router.get('/api/v1/products', addProduct)
then server.ts :
const port = 5000;
const app = new Application();
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());
console.log('Server running on port ${port}');
await app.listen({ port });

Please let me know if you need any further information.
PS: to test my queries I use Postman
I obviously tried to remove the parentheses but in this case it does not retrieve the body inserted on Postman (raw) and just returns success true. I tried to follow parallel solutions found but not being an expert, I cannot understand and adapt them

How exactly addProduct is used within your code?

As a sidenote, hasBody is considered to be unreliable.

I found a solution !
The extension Deno on VsCode choose the latest version of Oak when import but in the last I think that body() is not a function of request anymore. So I take the v6.5.0, no problem for the moment.
Also maybe is not the solution but it keeps me going

can you please try this solution
import { Request, Response } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const addProduct = async ({ request, response }: { request: Request, response: Response }) => {
    const body = await request.body();

    if (!request.hasBody) {
        response.status = 400;
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: "No data",
        };
    }
    else {
        const product: Product = body.value;
        products.push(product);
        response.status = 201;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: product,
        };
    }
};


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answers that consist of nothing else but code are considered low-quality and might get downvoted and deleted. Add explanations why the OP got the mentioned error and what's the difference in your code, so that doesn't have this error. Did you even test it?
